# Get NSArray key values

Tags: ios, json

I'm still noob with objective c code (PHP background). So I'm building this iphone app that connects to a web service. So far I've managed to retrieve JSON results and parse it through SBJson. However my problem is the array looks more or less like this:

```
MP = {
        name = "Muscle Power";
        desc = "";
        price = "100";
     };
A9 = {
        name = "Armotech 9000";
        desc = "";
        price = "200";
     };
T10 = {
        name = "Titanium 10";
        desc = "";
        price = "300";
      };
```

How do I get the value of the keys? as they are the codes to each item.
Plan to display it in UITableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the data structure you're referring to is a dictionary, or `NSDictionary` in Objective-C. Whereas many languages use the term `array` to refer to a list of objects, [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are ordered maps with keys and values.

`NSDictionary` provides a method called `allKeys`, which returns an `NSArray` of the keys in the dictionary. For example:

```
// Create a dictionary for the purposes of this example.
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"one", @"key1",
                      @"two", @"key2",
                      nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [dict allKeys]); // => ("key1", "key2")
```

Although this answer isn't specific to `SBJson`, if I recall correctly JSON results are returned as `NSDictionary` objects in that library, so you should be able to use `allKeys`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom object as shown [here](http://jasarien.com/?p=428)
Try it and let me know if it helps.